# Visual Studios 2010 C# sql database read only error

Tags: c#, sql, database, visual-studio-2010

Im working on a visual C# project with a local sql database. When I install the .msi file and run the program and then try to update something in the database I get the error "Failed to update database C:\setup\DBNC.mdf because the database is read-only" Im really having a hard time figuring this one out, any suggestions??

Answer (score 5):

I'm gonna bust out my magic 8 ball for a minute.  Let's see...

Is OP creating the database from a .sql script run on the local server?
*Reply hazy, try again*

Is OP including the .mdb in the install package?
*You may rely on it*

Okay.  So the database is being copied to that specific directory by the user via the install package...

Is OP elevating to admin when running the install package?
*Outlook good*

Okay, so OP is creating the directory and copying the file there during install, all under the aegis of the admin account.

Is OP attaching this file to a local instance of Sql Server?
*Signs point to yes*

Is the database configured as read only in Sql Server?
*Reply hazy, try again*

Has OP run ALTER DATABASE DBNC SET READ_ONLY?
*Don't count on it*

Okay, then has OP updated the NTFS security on `C:\setup\` and the mdb to give read/write access to the account that is running Sql Server (NETWORK SERVICE or some other account)?
*My sources say no*

**Bingo!**

You create that directory as admin and copy the file there.  The account running Sql Server does not have rights to alter the file, so you're getting that error.

You shouldn't deploy databases as files.  You should create a .sql file which creates the database and all tables/relationships/etc within it.  That way you are always assured the database can be accessed by the Sql Server instance.  Also, its easier to version a sql script file than a mdb.

Comment: Thanks Will that makes scene and helps a lot! Im still quite the noob with this could you tell me how to make a .sql file from my database, Im not seeing any place in visual studios to export it.

Comment: @user771886: From Server Explorer, right click on the database and select "Publish to Provider."  You can "publish" to a sql script from there.

Comment: That worked, Also dumb question but how do i then get my application to use the new .sql file instead of the old .mdf one, cause its looking for a DBNC.mdf file when the program runs

Comment: @user771886: I have no idea.  Depends on too many things.  Short answer--change your code to stop looking for it--doesn't exactly cut it.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this helps someone out there. I ran into a similar problem but resolved it by deploying my database files to the App Data directory and modifying my connection string to point there instead. This magically solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the properties of the .mdf file to make sure it's not read-only?  Sounds like that may be the problem.